# UX Resources for HF engineers

Tags: ux-integration

I'm looking for resources which are a good introduction for Human Factors engineers to help learn UX methods, techniques and tools which may not be part of a traditional HF education.

I come from a software development background so the domain seems very natural to me, but we have a separate HF team who don't come from a software background. There are plenty of complimentary skills and methods, but often the outputs can be different or ontology quite different.

I've found lots of resources, in particular pluralsight videos which aim to teach UX to software developers but nothing which really targets HF as a background.

Can anyone point me to anything dedicated, or specific examples which might resonate with an HF engineer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen some publications that appear to be written to provide standards/guidelines for engineers wanting to apply HF design practices, such as:

- AAMI TIR51: 2014/(R)2017 Technical Information Report, Human factors engineering — Guidance for contextual inquiry
- AAMI TIR59: 2017 Integrating human factors into design controls

There are also more specific reference materials such as:

- SA TS ISO 16976.5:2015 Respiratory protective devices - Human factors - Part 5: Thermal effects
- SA TS ISO 16976.2:2015 Respiratory protective devices - Human factors - Part 2: Anthropometrics

So I think there are plenty of resources but you would have to know where to look for them, and that's something probably better answered by engineers that also have an interest in UX design.

Comment: I think this is the closest I've found too, specifically this ISO https://www.iso.org/standard/52075.html

To be fair, I think I was really after more like visual design principles applicable to UX in the context of web design which might not be taught in HF degrees.

Comment: @dougajmcdonald I suggest updating the question to be more specific about this, but if you look at any materials talking about the gestalt principles and also the book "Universal Principles of Design" you will find more information.